# How to convert US date format to MYSQL format in INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql

I have following insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `bid`.`bdate` (`id`, `bid`, `odate`) VALUES (NULL, '1', STR_TO_DATE('02-27-2011 17:58','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
```

But it is giving me errors. Can some one guide me what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the date formats in the wrong place. Change your query to:

```
STR_TO_DATE('02-27-2011 17:58','%m-%d-%Y %H:%i'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont have a place holder for %s.

try this.

```
INSERT INTO `bid`.`bdate` (`id`, `bid`, `odate`) VALUES (NULL, '1', STR_TO_DATE('02-27-2011 17:58:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$datetime = strtotime($row->createdate);
$mysqldate = date("m/d/y g:i A", $datetime);
```